# Module with the Main dispatcher is missing. Add dependency providing the Main dispatcher, e.g. 'kotlinx-coroutines-android'

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I try to create my own Xamarin Android Library Binding.
The build process is okay.

But when I run some method on the library, it throws an exception

> Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'Module with the Main dispatcher is missing. Add dependency providing the Main dispatcher, e.g. 'kotlinx-coroutines-android''

I've tried to add **EmbeddedReferenceJar** to **kotlinx-coroutines-android** and **kotlinx-coroutines-core** but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably related to this [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3348) in Xamarin.Android.
Was fixed in v 10.1, see the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/10/10.1).

So just try to update the Visual Studio (possibly to the latest Preview version)